# g.renderer is null. And sometimes is not

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, wmts

I have an **`TypeError: g.renderer is null`** while I'm loading my map application. The worst is that problem sometimes happens, sometimes not.

```
require([
    'dojo/parser',
    'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
    'dijit/layout/AccordionContainer',
    'dijit/layout/BorderContainer', 
    'app.js',
    'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function(parser, ContentPane, AccordionContainer, BorderContainer){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        mapApp = new MapApplication();
        mapApp.prototype = MapApplication.prototype; //dziedzicz

        //access to constructors - no need to load it twice
        mapApp.ContentPane = ContentPane;
        mapApp.AccordionContainer = AccordionContainer;
        //
        parser.parse();
        $.getJSON(mapApp.CONFIG_FILE, function(json){
            if (json.app)       mapApp.initApp(json.app);
            if (json.map)       mapApp.initMap(json.map, json.widgets);
        });
    });
});
```

[image: Error]

Maybe it can be a clue that inside `initMap` I use another `require`, but anyway code does not reach this place because I would know (I have debug logs in `initApp`, `initMap` and so on).

Another reason I guess may be that I don't use basemaps. I load WMTSLayers and treat them as baselayers (but when loading is done, spatial reference is set properly)

My suspect is `parser.parse()`, but I have no idea what could be wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I solved problem myself. Error is not showing right now. I change my ArcGIS API src from

```
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
```

to a local file with code from this url.

```
<script src="libs/arcgis-api.js"></script>
```

I think problem was connected with weak network and some modules could not load properly. But I am not completely sure though.